# Jump to next line in .txt file in C

Tags: c, arrays, text

I need to make some actions from txt file.
What I was willing to do:

1. Calculate number of lines in txt
2. Open txt file
3. Iterate for each line
4. Iterate within each line and perform the task within it
5. Close file

Current code:

```
int lines(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("somedata.txt","r");
    int ch;
    int count=0;   
    do{
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if( ch== '\n') count++;   
    }
    while( ch != EOF );  
    fclose(fp);  
    return count;
}

int main(){
    int linesnum=lines();

    FILE *fp = fopen("somedata.txt", "r");
    if (fp == 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to open test0.txt\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    float areas[linesnum];
    for (int j=0;j<linesnum;j++){
        float array[150];
        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
                    fscanf(fp, "%f", &array[i]);
                    if (getc(fp) == (int)'\n'){ 
                    //that ends iteration for a line once it founds "\n"
                    //and assigns its value to temporary array
                        break;
                    }
        }

    //SOME TASK PERFORMED OVER HERE FOR EACH LINE lets say calculate average

        if (getc(fp) == EOF){ //That's supposed to be end of iteration through lines
                break;
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

File is in format (max lines 1000, max elements in each line is 150).

Number of elements in each line is different, so if I make a big matrix of 1000x150, most of elements will be empty; that's why I don't want a matrix, and just simply want perform task for each line.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 3 2 5 6 7 3 5
1 3 3 2 5 2 3
5 3 4 2 52 5 6
```

Well, I'm ending up with error Segmentation fault: 11 after performing task for 1st line.

I'm not sure how do I jump to next line after 1st iteration. That's the question.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Just had to get rid of EOF break thing in `main()`:

```
if (getc(fp) == EOF){
    break;
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to reopen the file after finding the line number. What if somebody else changes the file in between? Also, you don't close the `FILE*` you `fopen()`ed in `lines()`.

Comment: @EOF just my algorithm, it takes just few seconds to complete the actions, nobody will change file :) i just need a tip how to do task for next line.

Comment: @EOF thnx i closed file. :)

Comment: As @EOF says opening multiple times is bad. Use rewind return the file point er to the beginning of the file and clear errors. To process line 2 use your modified lines function as a guide to skiptoline function. This leads to an inefficient process all, but achieves a good modular standard program.

Comment: @rhubarbdog whats about the function skiptoline? cant find description on web. will be really helpful

Comment: You would be wise to declare the file name *once* in a variable or a `#define` so that you don't get silly error messages. And if you take the attitude of "this and that won't happen" you'll just end up with flaky code that falls over. For example, you haven't checked the return value from `fscanf`.

Comment: You have to write it or at least copy and paste it. It's virtually identical to function lines except it has an extra argument lines, each time \n is encountered decrement this variable. Adjust the while condition to (Ch!=EOF && lines!=0).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work.
Read a line with fgets. The line must be large enough to hold the longest line.
Use a pointer to line and an offset to parse the values from the line.
%n will receive the number of bytes used by the sscanf so the pointer can be advanced to the next value.

```
char line[1500];
char *pline;
int used = 0;
int i = 0;
int linesnum = 0;
float array[150];

while ( fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), fp))) {
    pline = line;
    i = 0;
    while ( ( sscanf ( pline, "%f%n", &array[i], &used)) == 1) {
        pline += used;
        i++;
        if ( i >= 150) {
            break;
        }
    }
    linesnum++;
    if ( linesnum >= 1000) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx man, was thinking of decreasing iterations amount and break loops when its either "\n" and "EOF"